# Date (itself) changed after Carbon formatting

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have date:

```
$date = "2017-09-09 14:06:56"
```

I do:

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s', $date);
```

I get:

```
Carbon {#491 ▼
  +"date": "2017-06-09 14:00:56.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

Why Carbon does not like September?
As well, look at the time, 6 minutes are lost.
WTF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct your carbon call:

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

Minutes notation is `i` not `m`.
When you use `m` twice, it has this unusual behavior.

Check this for reference on dates: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php